# How can I listen to a System.exit() with an error in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I`m currently trying to handle cases in my app for exiting, such as `Application.Exit` (Both via `.xml` and in `.xaml.cs`), `Dispatcher Exception`, etc.

However, I can't seem to find any way to simply listen to a `System.exit()` command with an error. An example of this is when the app is running and it is stopped in Visual Studio (Shift+F5), where it logs that a `System.exit(-1)` happened.

Is there a way to listen to this in the `Application` context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe to the closing and/or closed event in your view.
If you subscribe to the events in your main view this may do the job for you.